# como imprmir a pdf sin que me cambie el relleno del boton (bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

estoy realizando un catalogo en html con bootstrap pero resulta que al darle imprimir a la pagina en la vista previa me deja sin rellenos los botones, saben que puede ser?, al cargarlos en el navegador los muestra rellenos pero cuando le das a imprmir pasa eso. Saludos

Comment: En la vista previa activa gráficos de fondo.

Comment: Gracias era eso, saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Era lo que dijo @HERRERA, en la vista previa hay que activar gráficos de fondo, Gracias amigo.